# Sorting strings characters in Python and test the first letter in string

Tags: python

```
def a_letter(string):
  s = string.lower()
  if s[0] == 'a':
    return 'alpha'
  else:
    return 'zebra'
```

This code is testing the first letter of a string - if it's an 'a' then return `alpha`, else return `zebra`. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: You do *not* print `'alpha'`, you **return** `'alpha'`.

Comment: What's wrong with your way? Looks like a classic.

Comment: What in case the string is empty?

Comment: >is there a better way to do this

What does 'better' mean to you? A solution that is faster, has less code, is more readable or what?

Comment: You could get rid of the `else` if you really want to.

Comment: Here's a one liner, though I think your solution is fine: `return 'alpha' if s and s[0].lower == 'a' else 'zebra'.`

Comment: If the code is working, a better place to ask would be [codereview.se]. (Why should we have all the fun.)

Comment: still an intermediate python coder, so i think pros can have a better way than this...thanks y'all

Comment: @sammiie if you want a code review there is special stack exchange community for this (named Code Review obviously).

Answer (score 3):

I think a good way to do so is:

```
def a_letter(s):
    return 'alpha' if s and s[0].lower() == 'a' else 'zebra'
```

Because it is clear and sufficiently concise.

Comment: using slice avoids index error, so you can not check if string is empty: `return 'alpha' if string[0:1].lower() == 'a' else 'zebra'`

Comment: @splash58 better yet `string[:1]`

Answer (score 1):

If you have only two conditions you can try something a poor-man's [conditional expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394809/does-python-have-a-ternary-conditional-operator)

```
print(['zebra','alpha'][string[0].lower() =='a'])
```

How it works ?

```
True == 1, False == 0
```

because booleans are a subclass of int , so `[string.lower()[0]=='a']` produce a integer value but `['false','true']` takes it as index value.

Comment: It's cute, but in the real world I'd much prefer OP's code.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing inherently wrong with being explicit. Maybe you should protect against the empty string as pointed out by [Willem Van Onzem](https://stackoverflow.com/users/67579/willem-van-onsem) in the comments. You can do that - for instance - by using [`str.startswith`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith) which is the built-in way to check for prefixes. And are there shorter ways? - Sure:

```
return ('zebra', 'alpha')[s.startswith(('a', 'A'))]
```

Or maybe more readable, using the ternary operator:

```
return 'alpha' if s.startswith(('a', 'A')) else 'zebra'
```

Answer (score 0):

Do a more comprehensive solution, return something for *every* letter

voc=  converts the list of nato alphabet names to a dict mapping of letter to name

def phonetic checks the input is in the dict and then returns the value, or ? if it is confused

```
voc=dict([[string.lower(x[0]), x] for x in 
['ALFA',
 'BRAVO',
 'CHARLIE',
 'DELTA',
 'ECHO',
 'FOXTROT',
 'GOLF',
 'HOTEL',
 'INDIA',
 'JULIETT',
 'KILO',
 'LIMA',
 'MIKE',
 'NOVEMBER',
 'OSCAR',
 'PAPA',
 'QUEBEC',
 'ROMEO',
 'SIERRA',
 'TANGO',
 'UNIFORM',
 'VICTOR',
 'WHISKEY',
 'XRAY',
 'YANKEE',
 'ZULU']])

def phonetic(letter):
    if letter in voc:
        return voc[letter]
    else:
        return "?"
```